# SaveFileDialog C#

Tags: c#, winforms

День добрый! Столкнулся с интересным событием, может быть кто нибудь объяснит, в чем проблема. Сам чего - то не допираю. Есть SaveFileDialog, вот код:

```
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "csv-file|*.csv";
        sfd.Title = "Export csv file";
        sfd.ShowDialog();
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
             // тут мой код
        }
```

Так вот при нажатии кнопки отмены на диалоге, он закрывается и... снова открывается. При повторном нажатии ОТМЕНА закрывается на совсем. Подскажите, с чем это связано может быть? Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, читайте свой код внимательнее:

```
sfd.ShowDialog(); // <-- первый раз
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
//        ^ второй раз.
```

Делайте так:

```
var result = sfd.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Никак не думал, что он из условия тоже открывать станет.

Comment: @Юрий_Смирнов: а функция ж не знает, что вы её вызвали из условия! Вызвали — значит, надо показывать диалог, рассуждать «надо-не надо» не её дело.

Comment: Нам примерно так же ротный в армии говорил :)

Comment: @Юрий_Смирнов: Ну так :-) Приказы не обсуждаются, приказы выполняются. Только в случае с компьютером мы отдаём приказы.